# Find all points reachable in given time by car

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of about 3000 points (lon,lat) and I need to create an application to find for any given position on map (lon, lat) all points from this list, which are reachable in 10 minutes by car.
I can easily calculate this task for distance in metres, eg. all points inside a circle, but I need to do it using duration in minutes, not distance in metres.
Which part of Google Maps API should I use?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you'll need to use the [Google Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). However, because of the limits, you'll probably need to get crafty with filtering the list of possible locations before sending the request.

- **100 elements per query.**
- **100 elements per 10 seconds.**
- **2,500 elements per 24 hour period.**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a [isochrone map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map)

I would suggest something like [this](http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html) (a v2 example by [Marcelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo)).  The original is gone, [here is a copy](http://geocodezip.com/v2_marcelo_driveTimePolygon.html), and [a version ported to the v3 API](http://geocodezip.com/v3_marcelo_driveTimePolygon.html).

Start by drawing a circle (or not, but conceptually) with a radius that is greater that 10 minutes driving time (10 miles should work).  Find all the points in your database in that circle (that are less than the radius/10 miles from the center point).

This should narrow down your points to a manageable number. Use the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) to further refine the number, eliminating those that are within the circle but greater than 10 minutes away.

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveD.html)

- uses the places search for locations, pares down the results to those in a 10 mile radius, then sends those results to the DirectionsMatrix, discarding any results with a duration of greater than 10 minutes.